# Save Excel Sheet text only to text file VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the values of one column in a sheet to a text file. The code I currently have causes runtime error 434.

```
Sheets("Output to fcf.1").Columns("A").SaveToText "P:\4_Calcs\02. Flag Mapping\test_.txt"
```

If I try and save the whole sheet

```
Sheets("Output to fcf.2").SaveToText "P:\Clear Project Drive\CLE10276 AWS SMP Model Assessmnts\4_Calcs\02. Flag Mapping\test2_.txt"
```

I get the entire sheet converted into text rather than just the text in the sheet. Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure which Excel version you have but I don't see a method for `SaveToText`.

But this procedure should work, or at least get you started...

```
Sub SaveColumn(sheetName As String, columnName As String, fileName As String)
  Dim cell
  Dim fso
  Dim file

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set file = fso.CreateTextFile(fileName, True)
  For Each cell In Sheets(sheetName).Columns(columnName).Cells
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
      file.WriteLine cell.Value
    End If
  Next
  file.Close

  Set file = Nothing
  Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

To call it...

`SaveColumn "Output to fcf.1", "A", "P:\4_Calcs\02. Flag Mapping\test_.txt"`

Answer (score 2):

This is designed to be used as a macro.

**Step by step guide:**

1) From excel, hit Alt+F11 on your keyboard.

2) From the menu bar, click *Insert*, then *Module*

3) Copy and paste the code provided below into the new module that opens.

**NOTE:** `DocPath = "C:\docs\data.txt"` should be wherever you want the output file saved, including the file's actual name. Remember, the folder you want the output file to be located in should ALREADY exist. This does not create the folder if it can't be found.

4) From the menu bar, click *Tools*, then *References*. Make sure both "Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library" as well as "Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library" are checked, and hit okay ([See screenshot for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMYzd.png))

5) Save the document as an *.xlsm* file (This file type supports Macros)

6) Close the VBA editor. Back in Excel, on the ribbon click *View* and then *Macros*. Your new macro should be in the list as *ExportToTXT*

7) Select it and hit run.

```
Sub ExportToTXT()

  Dim DocPath As String
  Dim MsgBoxCompleted

  Columns("A").Select

  Dim AppWord As Word.Application
  Set AppWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

  AppWord.Visible = False

  Selection.Copy

  DocPath = "C:\docs\data.txt"

  'Create and save txt file
  AppWord.Documents.Add
  AppWord.Selection.Paste
  AppWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=DocPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatText

  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  AppWord.Quit (wdDoNotSaveChanges)
  Set AppWord = Nothing

  MsgBoxCompleted = MsgBox("Process complete.", vbOKOnly, "Process complete")

End Sub
```

Good luck, and if you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.

NOTE: These directions might seem overly simplified for your skill level, but I wrote the answer like this to potentially help others in the future.

**EDIT**

Change

```
DocPath = "C:\docs\data.txt"
```

to

```
DocPath = "C:\docs\data.fcf"
```

And change

```
AppWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=DocPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatText
```

to

```
AppWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=DocPath
```

The output file will be *.fcf* format. Whether or not it will open properly is something I'm not sure of. You'd have to test in the program you're using.

Comment: Is it possible to use this to save as a .fcf file extension (used by InfoWorks ICM) instead of .txt?